# Отложенное уничтожение объекта в VB6

Tags: объекты, visual-basic, vb6

Есть объект, который перед своим уничтожением должен дождаться какого-то асинхронного события. Как отсрочить это уничтожение, чтобы члены класса продолжали своё существование даже после `Set foo = Nothing`?

Пример: пусть это будет проигрыватель, использующий Waveform Audio API. Перед освобождением буферов он обязан дождаться оконного сообщения `MM_WOM_DONE`.

Явный вызов какой-то функции перед занулением ссылки неприемлем — хочется избежать утечки ресурсов по забывчивости пользователя класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объект может отсрочить своё уничтожение, если сохранит ссылку на самого себя внутри `Class_Teminate`:

```
Option Explicit

' Замените ThisClassName на имя этого класса
Private m_objPostponingReference As ThisClassName 

Private Sub Class_Teminate()
    Set m_objPostponingReference = Me

    ' Всё, объект начал существовать сам по себе. После завершения очистки необходимо
    ' выполнить Set m_objPostponingReference = Nothing, и объект будет окончательно удалён.

End Sub
```

Данный приём работает, потому что после возврата из `Class_Teminate` среда выполнения повторно проверяет счётчик ссылок и отменяет удаление, если он перестал быть нулевым.